# Disabling Toggle Functionality for a Specific Column in Bootstrap Table

Tags: bootstrap-table

I have column toggle functionality enabled on my Bootstrap Table. I would like to disable the toggle functionality for one of the displayed columns on the table. I read the documentation through this link: https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#column-options/switchable.html#view-source . However, I do NOT initialize my table columns as show in the example in the link. Instead, the following code is how I initialize my table columns.

[index.php]

```
<table

id="table"

data-toolbar="#toolbar"

data-search="true"

data-show-refresh="true"

data-show-fullscreen="true"

data-show-columns="true"

data-show-columns-toggle-all="true"

data-show-export="true"

data-minimum-count-columns="2"

data-pagination="true"

data-id-field="id"

data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, all]"

data-side-pagination="server"

data-response-handler="responseHandler"

data-url="data1.json">

</table>
```

[script.js]

```
\var $table = $('#table')
var $remove = $('#remove')
var selections = []

function viewFormatter(value, row, index) {

return [

'<a class="detail-btn btn btn-warning column-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)" role="button" title="Detail">',

'Detail',

'</a>

].join('')
}

function initTable() {

var icons = {

columns: 'bi bi-layout-sidebar-inset-reverse',

fullscreen: 'bi bi-arrows-fullscreen'

}

$table.bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable({

icons: icons,

height: 550,

locale: 'en-US',

columns: [
{

title: 'ID',

field: 'id',

align: 'center',

valign: 'middle',

sortable: true
},

{
title: 'Nama',

field: 'nama',

align: 'center',

sortable: true,

align: 'center'
}, 

{
title: 'E-mail',

field: 'email',

align: 'center',

valign: 'middle',
}, 

{
title: 'Nomor Telepon',

field: 'telepon',

align: 'center',

valign: 'middle'
}, 

{
title: 'Lokasi',

field: 'lokasi',

align: 'center',

valign: 'middle',

sortable: true
}, 

{
title: 'View',

field: 'view',

align: 'center',

formatter: viewFormatter

}]

})

$table.on('all.bs.table', function (e, name, args) {
console.log(name, args)
})
}

$(function() {
initTable()
})\
```

The column above that I would like to disable its column toggle ability is the 'View' column.

I saw in the 'Column Switchable' documentation of Bootstrap Table that if you initialized the table columns or fields through HTML, you can specify the 'data-switchable' option for a particular column/field to disable its column toggle ability. I thought it would be the same case for when initializing the table columns/fields through JavaScript where I can just specify column toggle ability using 'switchable' attribute and set to 'false'. Unfortunately, Bootstrap Table does not provide the equivalent functionality of 'data-switchable' on table initialization in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is a trick to know the equivalent name of the property to that of its attribute. What I mean is the documentation seems to encourage developers to define the table column headers through HTML instead of JavaScript. For example, the `switchable` column option in the Bootstrap Table documentation shows its usage as follow.

```
<table
  id="table"
  data-toggle="table"
  data-height="460"
  data-show-columns="true"
  data-url="json/data1.json">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th data-field="id" data-switchable="false">ID</th>
    <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
    <th data-field="price" data-switchable-label="Custom price label">Item Price</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

In defining the column headers, the `data-switchable` attribute is used to disable the column toggling for that particular column.

However, I initialize the Bootstrap Table using the example in the following link:

https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#welcome.html

Since I defined the column headers in JavaScript instead of directly in the HTML code like the example above, I cannot use the `data-switchable` attribute. And so, I try to guess what is its equivalent property name for that attribute. In the documentation, I saw that to define the title of the column header, the `data-title` is used if the table column headers are defined directly in HTML. Meanwhile, in my code as I initialize the table column headers in JavaScript, the title of the column headers uses the `title` property. And so, from there I thought that the equivalent property name of the `data-switchable` attribute must be `switchable` to which I can set to false to disable the column toggling for one of the column headers. Voila! It works.

Thus, if I want to disable the column toggle for this column header called `View`, I can just use the `switchable` property and set it to a Boolean value of `false`.

```
{
title: 'View',

field: 'view',

align: 'center',

switchable: false,

formatter: viewFormatter

}
```

I am still a web developer beginner so I apologize if anything I said may come out wrong. Hope this helps anyone who initialize the Bootstrap Table in JavaScript!